# How to send my response content to my view on Blazor?

Tags: c#, json.net, blazor

Hi cracks i have a component create  and this is how call and send info to controller

```
var resp = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<dynamic>($"AddOrdenFabricacionEspecial/{sessionTest.TokenAplicacion}", OrdenEspecial);
```

and this is my controller

```
        [Route("AddOrdenFabricacionEspecial/{llave}")]
        public async Task<dynamic> AddOrdenFabricacionEspecial(OWOR Json, string llave)
        {
            try
            {
                var urlBase = config["urlApi:url2"].ToString();
                var client  = new RestClient(urlBase+"OrdenFabricacion");                
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Json);

                request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + llave);
                request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

                IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

                return Ok($"{response.Content}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

i try to read after to response ok in controller , but i really lose in this, i cant obtain the string content from my var **Resp**

Ty all for read.

Comment: resp is of Type ```ActionResult```
What are you doing to get a string from it / what string are you hoping to get out of it?

Comment: hi @Chrotenise , well this case its special because "SAP" sent response status OK , when happend some error how , warehouse is not defined for the item , this return OK but its a error internaly in SAP, so this method originally was  public async Task<OWOR>  , so noramlly i return the obj ,  but now i have to send class error , for this i change to ActionResult , and also try with dynamic.
y hope to pass this response to my component

Comment: THIS

 {
    "error": {
        "code": -10,
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-us",
            "value": "The warehouse is not defined for the item.  [OWOR.Warehouse]"
        }
    }
}

Comment: I don't know what an `OWOR:Warehouse` is. I'd update your post tagging `SAP` and giving more details on what you want to happen. Right now you're asking us to tell you what is wrong with your particular approach, which might not fit your use case even if it works.